# Como visualizar os registros gravados no Core Data?

Tags: swift, xcode, osx, apple

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno App em **Swift** para **MacOS**, ia tudo bem até chegar no Core Data.

Consegui gravar e recuperar dados, tudo bem que não ficou tão bom quanto eu queria, mas já que é a primeira implementação, estou deixando passar.

Minha dificuldade está em conseguir visualizar graficamente os dados persistidos no Core Data, atualmente só estou conseguindo fazer isso via código. É possível abrir o "banco" para visualização pelo próprio Xcode? Se sim, como? Do contrário, qual a outra alternativa se é que ela existe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode visualizar o banco com o DB Browser for SQLite 
(https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl) abrindo o arquivo do CoreData

- No app delegate add este codigo para saber onde está o arquivo do banco no simulador

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
print("\(paths[0])")
```

- Rode o app e copie o caminho.
- abra o terminal e abra a pasta com o comando open + caminho copiado
- Entre na pasta Application Support e copie o arquivo CoreDataStack.sqlite
- Arraste o arquivo para o DB Browser for SQLite  e entre na aba Navegar dados